# Design problem with current mode boost converter with the PAM2423 comp?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost, switching-regulator

I'm trying to a boost conveter PAM2423 which workd at 520kHz for the first time(using a high quality breadboard from jameco for prototyping) following the manufacturer ref schematic:

[image]

My Setup:

[image]

[image]

I've soldered a 10uF input ceramic capacitor directlly to the chip

and unlike the manufacturer schematic I've added a 150OHM resistor between the VIN and EN pin because I've suspected shorting it directly burned the last IC.
I'm using the PA4341.682NLT 6.8uH 4.5A as the inductor if that matters(of course connected as closely as possible to the IC's output)

The PGND and AGND along with the button pad are connected to the same GND.

Here is the scope output connected between SW Pin of the IC and GND connected to an E-load @ CC 0.1A
with VIn = 4.2V and Average (not that stable) output voltage of 6.5V:

[image]
[image]

and @ No load VOut = 11.1V the SW output looks like this:

[image]

I'm not realy sure how to tune the COMP pin sins there is not alot of info in the datasheet about it(other than voltage setting no guide equations)
but increasing C7 and decreasing R3 seem to make things a little better.

What could be wrong about the design?
What exactly does that Compensation pin translates to?
Could the values in the schematic be wrong?

Comment: Use a 10:1 probe without a gnd clip or tip using two resistor wire stubs to connect.  Then use a small cap in feedback path to shunt R1 divider with RC = 200 ns going to Vfb. (2pf) avoid long lead lengths in feedback. Or scale down R1,R2 /10 and use 20 pF or so

Comment: A photo of your layout may help.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Excuse me but I was struggling to understand you, Do you mean to put a 2pF in parallel with R1? Russel McMahon updated the post with the pictures of my setup

Comment: Change R1, R2 to 850 ohms, 100 ohms as you have too much  stray crosstalk, and add 10nH/cm to your schematic and get rid of that scope probe and use a proper one as I said. You’ll never get textbook waveforms with that layout.

Comment: Yes this reduces overshoot

Comment: You won't obtain a reliable operation from a breadboard with long wires as you have. If you switch at 520 kHz, you can't avoid a compact PCB for these experiments, especially considering high peak currents in the inductor. You can short EN to VIN if this is recommended by the manufacturer. The COMP pin cannot really be tuned on the fly and you need a proper compensation strategy for this boost converter.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Yeah found that the probe was a total crap threw it right away, any recommendations for a proper reliable one? and I've got 1cm extra length which translates to 10nH extra which is only around 0.5% of the inductor values which doesn't seem that will have much of an effect and the thing with lowering the FB resistors values doesn't cut it I'll just proceed with making the PCBs sins I don't see any practical options to prototype it beforehand...

Comment: @VerbalKint So you say all of the switching regulators 
advances were only prototyped on a PCB?(RIP thousands of proto PCBs XD) I've just wondered what is that COMP pin actually to practically and how do you tune it? again the manufacturer doesn't provide any useful equations in the datasheet...

Comment: I have been working for a semi company developing dc-dc and ac-dc controllers/switchers and experiments are carried either on compact short-trace PCBs or on a veroboard at the very least. 3D-wiring sometimes also works but with short connections. I took a look at the PAM2423 data-sheet and it is a useless document for fine-tuning the loop. Having a proper documentation should be an argument to pick a part or not. If the components are poorly documented (empty data-sheet, no application notes etc.), stay away for the part and choose another brand. This is true for any other components.

Comment: Well I don't have many options to choose from as I need something that can take a VIn of < 2.8V VOut >= 24 and with 2A at least burst current capability as well as not that expensive less than 8$ or even 5$ per IC

Comment: parasitic inductance is unavoidable even with a 1mm Cap. This automatically creates a SRF resonance and with associated diode And FET Coss and has nothing to do with the inductor which is already cutoff by the transistor switching. What you have is a very high Q series resonance unless damped by the load. This is why layout is critical for the forward conduction loop path length and parasitic ESL and a variety of low ESR caps are essential to dampen the response over several decades of f.

Comment: Breadboards make this an impossible task to optimize without ground planes to lower the impedance.

Comment: @Pongo I have many times shown how to reliably probe with a 10:1 probe with a coil spring around tip & ring.  Go search

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 OK PCB it is and I have made that tip and barrel connector tip for some of my probes but it's inconviniet as it requires you to hold it in your hand while probing making it busy and sometimes it is challenging to find two exposed points near eachother to do the probing. anyway maybe a protoboard could do the thing for the next switching converter prototype? I've not had lick with that in the past but I suspect it was because of less experienced me or even more likely a fake switching IC from that cursed aliexpress... (Not ordering components from there anymore)

Comment: If you can find sockets for 2 pins and suspend the probe with tape for testing that sometimes is useful. A DIY etched board can be useful but ESL to the switched cap even at 0.8nH/mm will cause ringing unless we’ll damped with a load using low ESL twisted pairs. The comp pin is useful with the snubber C+RC circuit as well. But keep in mind the higher the efficiency means lower ESR, DCR Ron and higher Q with parasitic ESL. so keep those L/C ratios low for lower Impedance switching on wires means close to ground plane to increase C or shorter paths which is easier.

Answer (score 0):

This ringing is what you get from effective parasitic inductance (~1nH/mm) on long jumper wires without a star ground on chip and not using a ground plane. Ground leads are especially critical to lead inductance from switched caps. Thus then leads to excessive losses in the FET.

Your resonance may also be probe ground inductance.